# "Web App Launch View Activator" displays repeatedly in Progress tab on Eclipse during GWT development

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a fairly simple GWT application that when I run in dev mode shows "Web App Launch View Activator" in the Progress tab in Eclipse. This is causing me problems, taking up a chunk of processing on my machine and generally slowing things down. It does this for a while (a minute to several miuntes), then stops.

It does this every time I visit a new "page" in my application (i.e. launch a new Activity and add the associated view to the page) or trigger some UI activity, but not all. So, seems to happen when something new is added to the DOM maybe?

When it is displaying "Web App Launch View Activator" refreshing the browser to reload the application takes a very long time. If I wait for things to settle and the "Web App Launch View Activator" message is no longer displaying then a browser refresh is quite quick.

What is the Eclipse Google Plugin doing when it is displaying "Web App Launch View Activator", what triggers it and what can I do to reduce the impact on my development?

I'm running in Firefox 20.0.1 and IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The problem seems to be related to the log level used when launching the GWT application (as set by the -logLevel command line arg or on the GWT tab in the Eclipse Debug Configurations dialog).

I had changed this to DEBUG to highlight some other problems I was having and then left it at that setting. Changing it back to INFO and the repeating "Web App Launch View Activator" jobs in the Progress tab no longer appear.